# How to convert the given array into new array with some conditions?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array from which i want to create a new array

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object(
        [name] => Sam      
        [product] => Candy
        [group] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Sam
        [product] => Chocolate
        [group] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object(
        [name] => Dany
        [product] => Mobile
        [group] => 3
    )

[3] => stdClass Object(
        [name] => Dany
        [product] => Laptop
        [group] => 3
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Dany
        [product] => Computer
        [group] => 3
    ) )
```

From this array, I want to create a new array in which products with same group are combined :

```
Array(
[0] => array(
        [name] => Sam      
        [product] =>array( Candy, Chocolate)
        [group] => 1
    )

[1] => array(
        [name] => Dany
        [product] =>array( Mobile, Laptop, Computer)
        [group] => 3
    ) )
```

I am working in php and m not sure how to do it. Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Might you care to share those "conditions" with us as well, or are we to infer?

Comment: You want to convert stdClass to array ?

Comment: Actually i want to combine the products with same group

Comment: use foreach loop and use key as condition , for that condition all the elements  of first array will be added to second array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (isset($result[$value->group])) {
        $result[$value->group]['product'][] = $value->product;
    } else {
        $value->product = (array)$value->product;
        $result[$value->group] = (array)$value;
    }
}
```

If the keys in `$result` are of significance to you, use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) afterwards to reset them.